# Pass post id to page and query post (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, get

I'm trying pass a post id to a page and query that specific post on the page. To pass the id I'm using this:

```
<a href="http://mySite.nl/the_page?post_id=<?php echo $post->ID ?>">Edit</a>
```

This will pass the id to the page in the url. For example:

http://mySite.nl/the_page/?post_id=123

Now how will get the id out of the url to query it on the_page? Or is there another method to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use session ($_SESSION)http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$_REQUEST['post_id']
```